# how to write regular expression for this purpose?

Tags: regex, html-parsing

I want to write a regular expression to parse this webpage(view-source:http://www.imdb.com/search/title?title=spiderman&title_type=feature). Basically I want to extract all the sections between `<tr class=".+">` and `</tr>`. This webpage is a list of movies from imdb(http://www.imdb.com/search/title?title=spiderman&title_type=feature) and each section here indicates a movie. I tried the regular expression

```
<tr class=".+">(.+\n)+</tr>
```

However, it doesn't work. Also, I'm not allowed to use DOM. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Why aren't you allowed to use DOM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly suggest you use a proper parser. But here is the regex for your case.

```
<tr class="(.+)">([\s\S]+?)</tr>
```

Comment: Thank you, man! This solution is fabulous! I can't use a parser because it's a school project, the professor wants us to practice regex.